Redirect from subdirectory to WordPress plain permalink
I am hoping that this is a simple question, and if not would appreciate pointers for where I need to read up on this or post the question. I would like readers of print media to have a simple URL to type when trying to access various WordPress pages on my website. My site is currently set up with plain permalinks and don't want to change that (if possible). Would love folks to be able to type www.example.com/sample and get redirected to www.example.com/?p=123. Is the only solution to create a subdirectory called sample and add an .htaccess? I don't need any parameters or other nested directories. In a perfect world, the subdirectory in the URL would be case-insensitive (i.e. www.example.com/Sample == www.example.com/SAMPLE == www.example.com/sample all redirecting to one page).

There are a couple of Redirect plugins you could use for this, really streamline what you're after.  Question though, why would you not want to change the permalinks?

I have already pushed the plain permalinks out to a bunch of my customers who refer back. If I understand it correctly, if I change the permalinks they would get 404s using the old URLs.

I think that when you're using plain permalinks like ?p=123 that it should just automatically redirect to the new pretty permalink.  Let me test.

Yeah... ...so, if you go here:  https://bramptonsoccer.com/?p=3226  it will automatically redirect you to https://bramptonsoccer.com/getting-the-most-out-your-brampton-soccer-league/
:-)

Ah, cool beans! Guess I need to read up on permalinks.
